# What is the best way to keep one application android connected to the server

Tags: android, performance, push-notification, android-volley

I am developing an application in android where users can interact with each other. As a social network. So when a user1 performs an action, a notification to user2 is generated.

These notifications are stored on the web, under my hosting and domain. So that user2 can know that there is a new notification, you must send a request to my website asking if there are new notifications, and this one, respond. I am making this request with Volley.

Now, for notifications to be as instantaneous as possible, that is, that user2 displays them seconds after user1 generated it; I created a service that runs every 10 seconds.

**My concerns:**

1. Is it correct to make requests through Volley to a server every 10 seconds?
2. Is it correct to perform them every 5 seconds?
3. If it is not correct, what could you use to achieve the same goal?
4. Other applications such as Facebook or WhatsApp, how do they perform this type of action?

*Thanks for your time and help! :)*

**EDIT ADD 1**

WebSocket would be a good option but I use a shared server, and as I found it would not be possible. There is another option?

Comment: "I created a service that runs every 10 seconds", you can polling(continuously checking the server for update)? polling is a very bad approach to solve a problem.

Comment: no this is not correct. If there are no notifications for a day your app is just wasting resources. You should **send** notifications when something happens instead of asking over and over if there are any

Comment: Check websocket, it will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the best solution to this. But I would try using a webhook integration on your serverside that detects when an action is performed to perform another task. Such as generating the notification for the other user. Or you could use something like https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/tutorials/how-to-call-twilio-functions-android or you could use Firebase functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/ but would require switching your database to a firebase one I think.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it would not be a good practice. Firebase is a good option but I already have an infrastructure of functions and database on my server.

So it leads me to the option of using websockets, and it is not so complicated when it comes to implementing. Its only weak point is the need for a VPS or dedicated hosting service. If someone wants to know how to do it, here is the 4 video course on how to do it, which I found.
https://youtu.be/wlRgaaBT76Y